# Error verifying Smart Contract via Etherscan API due to evmversion

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, etherscan

I'm having an issue verifying contracts using Etherscan API when I use a different evm version from the standard compiler version.

In details I'm compiling using v0.8.21 and targeting to paris (for L2).

Once I submit verification via API like this:

```
curl --location 'https://api.etherscan.io/api' \
--form 'apikey="<MY-API-KEY>"' \
--form 'module="contract"' \
--form 'action="verifysourcecode"' \
--form 'contractaddress="<MY-CONTRACT ADDRESS>"' \
--form 'sourceCode="// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 */
contract Storage {

    uint256 number;

    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of '\''number'\''
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}"' \
--form 'contractname="Storage"' \
--form 'compilerversion="v0.8.21+commit.d9974bed"' \
--form 'optimizationUsed="1"' \
--form 'runs="200"' \
--form 'constructorArguements=""' \
--form 'evmversion="paris"' \
--form 'licenseType="3"'
```

I receive the following error:

`Fail - Unable to verify. Compiled contract deployment bytecode does NOT match the transaction deployment bytecode.`

It also fails if I try from the API demo here https://etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html

But if I manually verify from contract page itself on etherscan website, it works.

I think it is not reading `evmversion` parameter right via API.

Have you had any similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue on etherscan, bscscan, polygonscan and it has been addressed.
It is now working.

Check that comment from etherscan team https://twitter.com/vittominacori/status/1712755736848052609

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`--form 'compilerversion="<YOUR-COMPILER-VERSION>"'`

Here if you specify a different version than the one used to compile it will give you this error.

I compiled with the version `v0.8.18+commit.87f61d96` and specified the version in the flag and it works.

`--form 'compilerversion="v0.8.18+commit.87f61d96"'`

Of course you have to use this link for goerli: https://goerli.etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html

Comment: I already specify the compiler version here  
`--form 'compilerversion="v0.8.21+commit.d9974bed"' \`

The issue is that I compiled targeting to paris evm and it seems that the api is not using the evmversion parameter.